# Load the images from the input type file to a img

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm having some troubles trying to load more than one image (from an input type file) into a `<img>`.

I'm using this code for one file:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#img')
                .attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

In the case of multiples images, I have this HTML:

```
<section class="image-group">
                    <label class="lb_form" for="txt_img">Foto: </label><br><br>
                    <div class="img">
                        <img id="img0">
                        <img id="img1">
                        <img id="img2">
                        <img id="img3">
                        <img id="img4">
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                        <input type="button" value="Selecionar" class="frm-input btn"> 
                        <!--onchange="readURL(this)"-->
                        <input type="file" onchange="readURL(event)" id="files" name="txt_img" value="Selecionar" multiple> 
                    </div><br><br> 
                </section>
```

Each image must be in one of #img.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```js
function readURL(event) {
  let input = event.target;
  if (input.files) {
    Array.from(input.files).forEach((f, i) => {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#img' + i).attr('src', e.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="image-group">
      <label class="lb_form" for="txt_img">Foto: </label><br><br>
      <div class="img">
        <img id="img0">
        <img id="img1">
        <img id="img2">
        <img id="img3">
        <img id="img4">
      </div><br>
      <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
        <input type="button" value="Selecionar" class="frm-input btn">
        <!--onchange="readURL(this)"-->
        <input type="file" onchange="readURL(event)" id="files" name="txt_img" value="Selecionar" multiple>
      </div><br><br>
    </section>
```